# Using sas to compare one sets of dates with another sets of dates

Tags: arrays, date, sas, compare

My dataset looks like below:

```
ID   Date_of_infusion1   Date_of_infusion2...Date_of_infusion33   Labdate1   Labdate2  ...Labdate100
A     04/01/2016            08/06/2016               .           11/08/2017  10/21/2017      .
B     09/18/2015                .                    .           09/22/2015  09/30/2015      .
C     11/24/2015                .                    .           07/05/2015      .           .
```

What I want to do:
For each ID, if the labdate is after any of the infusion dates but within 4 months of that date(any infusiondate<=labdate<=the infusiondate+4months), then keep it; otherwise drop the labdate.

What I was trying to do:
make 2 arrays,one for infusion dates one for labdates. Then create a "flag" variable associated with Labdate.

I wrote something like this:

```
array infusion {*} date_of_infusion:;
array labdate {*} labdate:;
array flag {101} flag0-flag100;

do i= 1 to dim(labdate);
    do j=1 to dim(infusion);

    if infusion[j] ne . and infusion[j]<=labdate[i]<=intnx('month',infusion[j],4) then flag[i]=1;else flag[i]=0;
    end;

end;
```

However, the result doesn't look like something I want...

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: It will be easier to answer your question if you can provide a [complete reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including the output you're trying to create from the sample inputs.

Answer (score 1):

You have been so closed to your anwser.

When there is a piece of code and it looks 'right' but after it is submitted to the parser, the result is wrong, it is time to do some check and modify, called `debug`.

The basic technique for debug is print key message to the log and find the position of the occurrence of errors. So I add the `put` statement into your code:

```
data have;
  input ID$ (Date_of_infusion1 Date_of_infusion2 Labdate1 Labdate2) (mmddyy10. +1);
  format Date_of_infusion1 Date_of_infusion2 Labdate1 Labdate2 x e8601da.;
  cards;
  A 04/01/2016 08/06/2016 11/08/2017 10/21/2017
  B 09/18/2015 .          09/22/2015 09/30/2015
  ;
run;

data want;
  set have;

  array infusion {*} date_of_infusion:;
  array labdate {*} labdate:;
  array flag {101} flag0-flag100;
  do i= 1 to dim(labdate);
    do j=1 to dim(infusion);
      if infusion[j] ne . and infusion[j]<=labdate[i]<=intnx('month',infusion[j],4) then flag[i]=1;else flag[i]=0;
      if flag[i]=1 then put ID flag0-flag1;
    end;
  end;
run;
```

The log shows:

```
B 1 .
B 0 1
```

See, we had get flag0 = 1 but lost it in the next iteration. Just think about why it happens we quickly know that the loop should not continue when we have `flag[i]=1`. Else we would never get `flag[i]=1` unless all `date_of_infusion:` meet the judge expression.

So here is the result of debug.

```
data want;
  set have;

  array infusion {*} date_of_infusion:;
  array labdate {*} labdate:;
  array flag {101} flag0-flag100;
  do i= 1 to dim(labdate);
    do j=1 to dim(infusion);
      if infusion[j] ne . and infusion[j]<=labdate[i]<=intnx('month',infusion[j],4) then flag[i]=1;else flag[i]=0;
      if flag[i] then leave;
    end;
  end;
run;
```

Hope you enjoy the time of coding.